# Got a warning message in SAS Studio about it expiring

Tags: sas, sas-studio

Got a warning message:

[image]

...when opening up Sas Studio. I do not pay for it (it has been free to use, have been using it for half a year at least) Not sure what should I do, because I would like to keep using it and I would like to keep all my documents. Is the SAS Studio just a trial version? What do I need to do? Can I not use it after April 4? or should I just ignore it?

Comment: http://support.sas.com/kb/57/239.html

Comment: Is this a version installedon your local machine? From an academic institution? If so you need to renew it somehow. Otherwise, you can use Academics on Demand (as an individual without any affiliation to an academic institution) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore it. Just logged in to SAS On Demand and saw the same message. SAS will update the license and the message will go away.

https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Software-for-Learning/Please-ignore-expiration-warning-for-SAS-OnDemand-for-Academics/m-p/858792